# Can I consider "whole word" as the word with space isolated in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

Currently, if I have the following text

`5 0.5 4`

Then I do a "whole word only" replacement for `5` to `9`, I will get

`9 0.9 4`

instead of

`9 0.5 4`

So how can I get `9 0.5 4`? Is this doable within Notepad++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"whole word only" means that the word have word boundary around it, and, there is a word boundary between `.` and `5`.

I guess you want to replace `5` with `9` only if there are sapces around it, here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(^|\h)\K5(?=\h|$)`
- Replace with: `9`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:^|\h)    : non capture group, beginning of line or a horizontal space
\K          : forget all we have seen until this position
5           : the value to be changed
(?=\h|$)    : lookahead, zero-length assertion, make sure we have a horizontal space or end of line after the digit
```

**Result for given example:**

```
9 0.5 4
```